# I got build failed error while running Android Studio at first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I installed Android Studio 3.3.1. I open new project and it gives an error like this:

```
  Could not find method implementation() for arguments 
[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0] on object of type 

org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager.

I have no idea about that.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please refer to this reference on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

Try Update your gradle plugin to 3.x Or replace implementation with compile in your gradle file

Comment: please let me know what is your current gradle plugin version and what is the another error?

Comment: It says: ERROR: Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.